# How to create a picker view in IOS to select few dates

Tags: ios, swift

We want to create a pickerview where a person can select amongst given dates, e.g., 30-Jan-2020, 29-Feb-2020, 28-Mar-2020 & 26-Apr-2020. These dates will come from an API. Is there a way to create such a pickerview, where the dates shown in the pickerview are adjusted as per the device locale (like in the USA showing month before the date, in another geography date before month) and secondly can we directly convert the selected date into Swift Date as we do for dates selected from DatePicker.

Comment: Yes, but of course it will just be a picker view, not a date picker. You'll have to do all the grunt work yourself of dealing with all the date issues you listed (and probably others as well).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gaborcsontos/GMPicker 
You can use this library . Theres is class GMPICKER you can use that class.
Pass your custom dates in it . 
and for localization you can use DateFormatter .